# Protocol inheritance

Tags: clojure, protocols

Sometimes it is convenient to have an inheritance structure on interfaces:
For example:

- I want to define a `Functor` interface which provides `fmap` function.
- I want to define an `Applicative` interface which provides `fapply` and `pure` functions.

But every applicative functor is a functor: `(def fmap #(fapply (pure %1) %2))`.

The first solution I came to is the following:

- Define `Functor` and `Applicative` as independent protocols.
- Define `functor?` function which returns `true` for any `Functor` or `Applicative` instance.
- Define `fmap` mulimethod which can take `Functor` or `Applicative` and dispatches
  to `#(functor/fmap %1 %2)` or `#(applicative/fapply (applicative/pure %1) %2)`.

However this solutions smells as it looks like cheating a clojure type system.

The second solution is to define a macro `extend-applicative` which will automatically implement `Functor`  protocol. But this solution do not look great also as it requires additional work from user of the library and it allows sepparate definition of functor/applicative instances which can easily lead to an error.

Is there a better way to express this kind of relations in clojure?

Comment: What are you using to define the interfaces? `defprotocol`? `definterface`? How do you provide the concrete implementation? Note that via `extend-type` or `extend-protocol` you can implement multiple protocols at once. Also, it should be possible to `derive` Applicative from Functor, but this will not magically provide any user of `Applicative` with `fmap`.

Comment: Currently I'm defining interfaces as `defprotocol` and I'm using the first solution to emulate inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: As Thumbnail says, this turned out to be a faulty approach - I was only testing records implementing the *protocol interface* and didn't notice that *extending the Applicative protocol* didn't actually implement Functor.

Remember, `extend` does not require that the type being extended is a concrete implementation; <s>one protocol can extend another</s>you can extend interfaces and abstract classes, too. You should be able to do something like

### Applicative.clj

```
(ns protocol.applicative)
(defprotocol Applicative
      (fapply [f g])
      (pure [x] ))
```

### functor.clj

```
(ns protocol.functor
  (:import [protocol.applicative.Applicative])
  (:require [protocol.applicative :refer [fapply pure]])
  )

(defprotocol Functor
  (fmap [this f]))

(extend-protocol Functor
  protocol.applicative.Applicative
    (fmap [this f] (fapply (pure f) this)))
```

Multiple files and importing is my attempt to deal with some compilation order issues which come up; you'll also have to add the two to AOT. Hope that helps you get it working.

Comment: 1. In protocol description it is said that protocol extension is not supported to avoid problems with multiple inheritance of realisation. 

2. This solution does not work for me. I tried to extend applicative for a class `A` and for `a` - an object of class `A` `(satisfies? Functor a)` gives false, and `(fmap a f)` leads to an error: No implementation of method :fmap of protocol #'Functor.

Comment: 3. By the way, you are extending interface `protocol.applicative.Applicative`, not the protocol `protocol.applicative/Applicative` if you'll try to extend protocol, you'll obtain an error, as expected.

Comment: 4. As I understand `(fmap a f)` fails, because `A` extends protocol `protocol.applicative/Applicative`, but do not implements interface `protocol.applicative.Applicative`.  So the only way to use your approach - to implement java interface `Applicative` for every class, we want to make `Applicative`. I love this solution even less than solutions i proposed, because now the only place where we can implement `Applicative` interface for a class is class definition and we can not extend existing classes and collections.

Comment: Hmm. Guess that's what I get for testing just with a `defrecord` that implements the interface. Then I guess your other approach is definitely better.

Comment: As I understand it, this doesn't work. If so, please acknowledge this plainly in the answer itself. Brave but faulty efforts make good warning signposts.